# I'm having a bit of trouble when it comes to "while" statements in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

This is a Java problem. I'm having a bit of trouble operating a while loop inside this "if" statement hanging around in the KeyListener. It is a bit frustrating trying to loop my rectX -= snakeSpeedY.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        AUTO = false; //boolean for automatic movement FYI.
        while (snakeMoving == true) {//another boolean, for stoping and moving the snake
            rectY -= snakeSpeedY;
        }
```

I'm wondering if the "if" statements can't handle while-loops? Am I doing it wrong? All feedback would be appreciated.

EDIT: I focused mainly on this proportion of my code because this was where the problem happened. I'm sorry for not including the "If" brackets.

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of the code. Also clearly state the expected behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: You're missing a closing brace `}` to begin with. The `if` has nothing to do with the `while`. Further, since the while-loop doesn't change the value of `snakeMoving` - it would never exit the loop. And last, please please please fix your indentation to comply with http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? This is not code review forum.

Comment: @Renny getKeyCode return int.

Comment: I had the closing brace for the if statement. I was only showing a fragment of the code I programmed myself. I'm sorry for any confusions.

Comment: To do it properly, you need to learn about Timer etc. Try to understand this code and tutorial: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/snake/ then write it on your own from scratch. BTW, there is not a single while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Watch where you closing brackets ("}") are - it is always a source of beginner errors, but especially when there are loops. You did not close the bracket for your "if" statement. But also it is important where exactly do you put it.
2. while the loop is looping, the variable used in the condition should be changed. Either inside the loop, or, in more complex scenarios, *during* the loop runtime on a different thread. The only other possibility to end the loop is to call "break;". You did not seem to do any of the three. So you got yourself an infinite loop.

Comment: I had an if statement bracket, its just the while wasn't working for an unexpected reason.

Comment: @CA1K , You have an infinite loop as Alex mentions. I think you wanted an 'if' instead of 'while' or do not need both of them

Comment: Your while loop is such that within about 1 second it will reduce rectY by millions or billions of pixels. Loops are very fast. You should repaint your snake *inside* your loop. But for a snake game you should not use the loop at all here.